# How to get numeric data from the "object" data type and make it "int" in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When loading securities quote data, the price values ​​look like this:
Where units is the integer part, nano is the fractional part.

```
| close                               | volume     | time
| {'units': 270, 'nano': 190000000}   | 51642      | 2023-12-29 07:30:00+00:00
| {'units': 270, 'nano': 930000000}   | 47910      | 2023-12-29 08:00:00+00:00
| {'units': 271, 'nano': 0}           | 49376      | 2023-12-29 08:30:00+00:00
```

How can I fix the "close" column so that the data looks like this?

```
| close   | volume     | time
| 270.19  | 51642      | 2023-12-29 07:30:00+00:00
| 270.93  | 47910      | 2023-12-29 08:00:00+00:00
| 271     | 49376      | 2023-12-29 08:30:00+00:00
```

I tried to sum the values as follows, but nothing came out.

```
def cost_money(v):
   return v.units + v.nano / 1e9
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Convert dictionaries to `DataFrame` by [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) and then create new column:

```
v = pd.json_normalize(df['close'])
df['close'] = v.units + v.nano / 1e9
```

But if there are strings repr of dictionaries first convert them:

```
import ast

v = pd.json_normalize(df['close'].apply(ast.literal_eval))
df['close'] = v.units + v.nano / 1e9
```

---

```
print (df)
    close  volume                       time
0  270.19   51642  2023-12-29 07:30:00+00:00
1  270.93   47910  2023-12-29 08:00:00+00:00
2  271.00   49376  2023-12-29 08:30:00+00:00
```

Youe solution:

```
import ast

def cost_money(v): 
    #if necessary convert string repr to dicts
    v = ast.literal_eval(v)

    return v['units'] + v['nano'] / 1e9

df['close'] = df['close'].apply(cost_money)
```